# Fancybox-2 on mobile - prevent scrolling of the page behind popup

Tags: jquery, ios, css, mobile, fancybox-2

*I cannot find the same issue online after over a day's searching, so I am here with tail-between-legs.*

Not sure what code is relevant to this issue - can provide - otherwise see link below

I am working on a image gallery for a portfolio site. Using fancybox2, everything is working as intended on desktop version but there is a minor issue for mobile devices (testing on an iPhone 4).

Page with issue: [CLICK HERE](http://www.redlaurieyellowlaurie.co.uk/tom/film_test.html)

Screenshot of issue: [SCREENSHOT OF ISSUE ON MOBILE](http://www.redlaurieyellowlaurie.co.uk/tom/issue.png)

**Current Behaviour =** When the user taps on the thumbnail to load up the full size image, the image loads up correctly in a pop-up window, with the 'x' to close in the corner, the user can then finger-swipe down to scroll down the page, whilst the pop-up is still open. The rest of the page is darkened whilst the image is 'open'and tapping the page elsewhere will close the image.

**Desired Behaviour =** When a pop-up image is open, finger scrolling the page behind image is prevented until the window is closed (by X-ing in the corner or tapping outside the popped-up image).

aside- Perhaps finger gestures should switch between images in the same gallery - although this may be too complicated (for me) to implement for now.

I am working out how to use JS as I go along, so any baby-steps advice will be recieved with gratitude.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I need this too, did you find a fix for this ?

Answer (score 4):

I've run into that once & these are the lines that solved the problem:

```
   FancyboxOptions({
      scrolling   : 'hidden',
      helpers: {
         overlay: {
            locked: true 
         }
      });
```

I hope it's relevant to your situation :-)

Comment: It makes me sad that I found myself here in 2018.  Thank you!

Comment: This option doesn't exist --> scrolling   : 'hidden' 
it be Can be set to 'auto', 'yes', 'no' or 'visible.